# How to view ones old messages (older than 1 month)

Tags: github

In 'contribution activity' section, messages can only go up to 1 month. Likewise in 'public actibity'. How to search for the rest?

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding) or direct to GitHub:Support